# Error to deploy a webapplication into weblogic

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

I have a webapplication that is using maven to build. When I try to deploy it into weblogic 10.3.5.0 I got the follow erro:

```
Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNot
PresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumArray(AnnotationPars
er.java:693)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.j
ava:482)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationPa
rser.java:306)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationPar
ser.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationP
arser.java:88)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: take a look at this answer and see if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816831/1570834

Comment: I looked it, but the solutions there didn't resolve, I got de same error yet.